# Apply style to second field

Tags: qgis, style

I created a point shapefile in QGIS 2.01. Then, I changed the style of the points so they display the contents of the *Acceleration* field in the attribute table. Works exactly as I require.

Now I would like to apply the same style to a second field in the table, but when I select that field in the *Style* dialog box, all the symbols are reset to their original display characteristics (colour, size). Is there a way to retain the current style definitions, and simply apply them to a second field? The value ranges are identical for both fields, so the same symbology could apply.

I tried to save the style using the *Save Style* button. Tried both options (*.qml and *.sld), but neither of them created a file. The *.sld option generated an error message that I should check the folder permissions, but that does not make sense because I've been using that folder to store the shapefiles.

Answer (score 1):

To the left of the save style button is one called save as default. This creates a file in the same folder as the .shp file with the same name as .shp set. QGIS looks for this file and will use it as the default style when loading. It is more consistent than Save Style.

What operating system does you computer use?

Comment: Computers are Windows 7. One is 32-bit, other 64-bit.

Comment: Thanks, that worked (mostly!).  I had to open the .QML file and edit the name of the attribute to match the name of the second field.